# Rider Invalid or strange Cache File Issue

Tags: c#, ide, rider

Doing a small Project in my rider IDE on mac m1.
Everytime, there would be some strange files generated, as the the following screenshot

[image]

As shown, there are three underscore files in the solution and I have to delete them everytime if I edit other file.
If I open the file, it is showing
[image]
I have tried to clean or invalidate cache in Rider, which doesn't help.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the logs for those file names. Recently I saw Roslyn analyzer doing weird things.